# bluemix serve onepage application

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to deploy an example in bluemix that make use of webpack using serve for serve the one page application compiled using the following on the package.js

```
"start": "serve -p 6003",
```

But have the following error

```
[HEALTH/0] ERR healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.1.102:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
```

What  I'm need to change to publish this app

I am pushing using: `cf push` and my manifest looks like this:

```
applications: 
- path: . 
  memory: 256M 
  instances: 1 
  domain: mybluemix.net 
  name: ktest2017 
  host: ktest2017 
  disk_quota: 1024M
```

To run the problem I'm make the following:

1. Create a node application in a bluemix account
2. Donwload the base project
3. Create a new vue.js cli webpack-simple app, and serve as one page application server
4. Generate the package.json start with :

   `"scripts": {
   "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
   "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
   "start":"serve -p 6003" 
   },
   "dependencies": {
   "serve": "^6.2.0",
   "vue": "^2.4.4",
   "cfenv": "^1.0.4",
   },
   "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
   "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
   "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
   "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
   "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
   "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
   "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
   "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
   "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
   "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
   "webpack": "^3.6.0",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
   }`
5. Run npm run build to geneate the js files
6. Run locally with npm start
7. Trying locally and works
8. Uploading to bluemix with CF cli
9. Display the error

   [HEALTH/0] ERR healthcheck failed: failure to make TCP connection: dial tcp 10.254.1.102:8080: getsockopt: connection refused

Maybe need to use another library to serve the one page application with vue.js

Comment: Can you share the command you are using to deploy and your manifest.yml?

Comment: Sure, thanks I use  from console:  `cf push`  and my manifest is like this 
`applications: 
- path: .
  memory: 256M
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: ktest2017
  host: ktest2017
  disk_quota: 1024M `

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I think I will need more information to understand what is going on.  Ideally, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you try adding a start command to your manifest or when you use `cf push` ([more info](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html#start))?  Note that you won't be able to specify a port when you run on cloud foundry as that will get allocated to you automatically ([more info](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html#port)).

Comment: As you say I remove the port on the start command in the package.json  and that works now thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Happy I could help. I've added an answer to close the question.  Please accept and vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Foundry decides which port your application runs on.  You cannot set this yourself.  See here for more info: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html#port